# WP cron doesn't pass through my arguments

Tags: actions, wp-cron, cron

I've been trying to import some posts trough a cron action. The problem is my last step. Everything is going well, except for the execution of the cron. It is only passing trough the first argument.

Which would (clearly) point at the following code

```
add_action( 'import_videos_recurring', 'import_recurring', 10, 3 );
```

But if I execute the following code for testing purposes (simplified code). It will still pass me only one argument.

```
function import_recurring_3( $args ) {

    var_dump( $args );

}


function add_timething() {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'minutly', 'import_videos_recurring_3', array(
        'user' => 'testding',
        'value' =>'testwaarde',
        'break' => true
    ) );
}

add_action('init', 'add_timething');

add_action( 'import_videos_recurring_3', 'import_recurring_3', 10, 3 );
```

I've read a couple of questions & answers on the exchange here. But can't find why the following code is not working.

Comment: With "one argument" you mean the whole `array`? Or...?

Comment: Nope, it only passes trough the first argument in the array.

Comment: Try using an associative array and use proper keys.

Comment: even if i do this (see edited question) nothing changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried:

```
function import_recurring_3( $args, $args2, $args3 ) {
    var_dump( $args );
    var_dump( $args2 );
    var_dump( $args3 );
}
```

And it worked. Just bizar.